# Inserting a multi dimensional associative array into an associative array

Tags: php, arrays

I have the following array:

```
Array ( [0] => Array ( [0] => 19132 [1] => 19133 [2] => 19134 ) )
```

and I would like to insert into the following function to create an associative array:

```
public function userPersmissions($summary, $dbName, $userId, $arisUserGroup, $arisFolderPath)
{
    $json = Array ( "fields" => Array (
        "project" => Array
        ( "id" => 19806 ),
        "summary" => $summary,
        "issuetype" => Array ( "name" => "User Permissions" ),

        "customfield_14922" =>Array (
            "id" => $dbName
        ),
        "customfield_14447" =>$userId,

        "customfield_14923" =>Array (
            "id" => $arisUserGroup
        ),

        "customfield_15579" =>$arisFolderPath

    )
    );

    return $json;
}
```

the array is passed into the function through the variable `$arisUserGroup`

But I get an error saying $arisUserGroup is not array, while I printed it out and sure that its an array.

I call the function this way:

```
try{
    //Capture

    $userGroup[] = Input::get('arisUserGroup');

    $process = $collector->userPersmissions(
        escape(Input::get('summary')),
        escape(Input::get('dbName')),
        escape(Input::get('acnumber')),
        escape($userGroup),
        escape(Input::get('arisFolderPath'))

    );

    $_SESSION['test'] = $collector->processArray($process);



}catch (Exception $e){
    die($e->getMessage());
}
```

Please assist

Comment: Show how you call that function `userPersmissions()`

Comment: I don't see any code that uses `$arisUserGroup` as an array. Are you sure that the error is thrown from the code you've posted?

Comment: As the other two comments mentioned it might be that when you call your function you have misaligned the parameters and they are not what you expect them to be.

Comment: So what does `escape()` do???

Comment: And what is `$userGroup;` doing sitting in the middle of knowhere just before the `catch`??

Comment: @RiggsFolly   escape() is just a function to escape HTML. It works well on all other forms, except this one with a multi-select field. I put $userGroup there by mistake, but removed it on my code

Comment: Does `escape()` work on arrays?? More importantly, does it return an array??

Comment: @RiggsFolly, yes, it does.

Comment: Its not being used on any arrays in the other calls!?!? Are you sure it returns an array, do a simple test `print_r(escape($userGroup));` what does that show

Comment: I removed to see, if I will get a different result, but still the same error

Comment: @kya show us the error message. You said it refers to `$arisUserGroup`, but you don't use the variable named `$arisUserGroup` as array anywhere in the code you posted. Also, try viewing exception stacktrace, not only message.

Comment: @Timekiller see `customfield_14923` and you will see where `$arisUserGroup` is being used

Comment: @RiggsFolly, I think the issue lies in the userPermission function, where I'm inserting the multi-select data into the customfield_14923. The format of the array is not the same. an array coming from the multi-select is different from that I push into the customfield_14923. Is there a way I can form them to be the same ?

Comment: @kya I see the variable there, but at this point PHP wouldn't care if it wasn't an array and wouldn't give you the error. You're not trying to access something like `$arisUserGroup[0]`, you're putting it verbatim inside another array. In this situation, PHP shouldn't care whether it's an array, string or null.